# Can firewall block connection over VPN?

Tags: root-access, vpn, 9.0-pie, firewall

I would like to block specific apps from making connection to internet. I sometimes am connected by VPN but not always. How can I make firewall work for both VPN and not VPN, wifi and mobile data? My phone has root.

Comment: Since you have root, you can use AFWall+ which is based on `iptables`. It doesn't require VPN, so you can use VPN apps freely.

Answer (score 0):

Android permits only one VPN to be working on the phone and that is the problem since firewalls also usually create a VPN and you are forced to switch off the VPN to make the firewall work.

However, there is a workaround, at least in some cases. I use [Adguard](https://adguard.com/en/welcome.html) which is an Adblocker with an integrated firewall. It creates it's own VPN on the device locally to filter ads. I also use [Keep Solid VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplexsolutionsinc.vpn_unlimited) which is set to *always use* in my settings (Pie) . Adguard has a *proxy mode* which permits both VPNs to be used and since your device is rooted, it is easier.

However, note :

- All VPNs may not work in this fashion. Check the Adguard forums.
- In proxy mode, the efficacy of Adguard firewall is reduced but in my case I have no problems in blocking internet access to apps.
- If I want only the Firewall functions but not Keep Solid VPN, I simply disconnect it from the notification panel.

To sum up, it's possible but you need to invest time in checking and ensuring both work.